# How do I select more Recast Mask layers for XR Ray Interactor at run time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to select more layers for Raycast Mask at runtime when I click a button.

I tried `GetComponent<XRRayInteractor>().raycastMask.` but couldn't find an option to select more layers

[image]